# Is my raster too large to realistically vectorize in ArcGIS Pro?

Tags: raster, arcgis-pro, vectorization

I'm new to ArcGIS Pro so go easy on me.  I have a raster file(.img) of the continental US broken up into 30x30m grid resulting in about 10 billion individual pixels.  I need to index each of these pixels and their class name to be heat mapped.

I've been trying to convert from raster to point, then fishnet the 30x30m grid, and intersect the two layers to get class names associated with the grids which I can later heat map.  Raster to point was slated to run for about 5 days in ArcGIS Pro and quit after about 1.5 days.  I then split the raster into 12 equaly sized rasters and tried running raster to point on each of these simultaneously in Python (I have a 12 thread cpu).  These are still currently running after 1 day...

A larger issue is that in that day I have gained almost 1TB of data comprised mostly of gbdtable files which are quickly filling up my PC.  Is my datasets too large to realistically analyze in this way?  Does anyone have any suggestions to speed things up?  I'm also looking into running this on a beefy virtual machine in the future if nothing else works.

Comment: What would you gain from creating a few terabytes of point tables?  If you want heat maps, you want a raster anyway. Instead of testing with massive datasets, you should prototype your processing steps with 30km*30km pixels, knowing that you'll need a million times more storage/time to see the process through. Keep in mind that geodatabase features classes are restricted to two billion features. Twelve simultaneous jobs on six independent disk devices would probably overwhelm most systems. Twelve simultaneous jobs on a single device is a recipe for thrashing.

Comment: I have data at the county level that needs to be heat mapped at the 30x30m level so I need to know in what county is the 30x30m pixel in and what class name for data merging purposes.  The purpose of the point tables is to be able to index each pixel at the county level.  I have prototyped this process with a single county and it works.  I haven't experienced any thrashing.

Comment: Fine. Run your one-county process 3142 more times.

Comment: Writing a python script using arcpy might be a helpful way to take your successful county-level protocol and iterate through all the 3142 counties.